# How to run Python, R, Octave or Julia using BowPad?

Tags: r

I try using a very light-weighted editor  [BowPad](https://github.com/stefankueng/BowPad)  to edit and run codes.

Take running R  as an example, which has been added to Windows PATH Environment Variable `D:\R\R-3.6.2\bin\x64`

I try to take some following steps:

- I built a `test.r` writing some testing line codes as `1+2; plot(1:10)`
- Menu --> Run --> Configure custom commands

  - Command Name:  `run R`
  - Command Line:  `D:\R\R-3.6.2\bin\R.exe $(SEL_TEXT)`

    - `$(LINE)          The line where the cursor is`
    - `$(POS)           the position where the cursor is`
    - `$(TAB_PATH)      the path to the file of the active tab`
    - `$(TAB_NAME)      the file name without extension of the current tab`
    - `$(TAB_EXT)       the file extension of the current tab`
    - `$(TAB_DIR)       the directory of the file of the active tab`
    - `$(SEL_TEXT)      the selected text or the word at the cursor position`
    - `$(SEL_TEXT_ESCAPED)  like $(SEL_TEXT) but escaped, useful for urls`

When I  press to choose `run R`  to run the code, something wrong happens!

- It will open a `Rterm(64-bit)`  window each time when I `run R`!
- it shows  `RGUMENT '1+2' __ignored__` or `ARGUMENT 'plot(1:10)' __ignored__`

Did I missing something ? BTW, can we set some shortcuts keys for running Python, R, Octave or Julia?

Also, when I reach the [homepage](https://tools.stefankueng.com/BowPad.html) of BowPad for more information, little usage of this software can be found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.exe refers to Rterm.  You can use Rgui.exe instead but that won't automatically process arguments.  I think what you likely want is to send the selected text to a running R session rather than starting up a new R session each time.

To do that

1. download this file and optionally place it on your path https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ggrothendieck/batchfiles/master/clip2r.js
2. in the Bowpad Run | Configure window configure a Run R command as the following (or if clip2r.js is not on your path use the entire pathname).  It should be just like this with no arguments.

   ```
    clip2r.js
   ```
3. From the Windows cmd line if Rgui is running we see that `tasklist | findstr Rgui`  finds Rgui as the R gui process and you can create additional js scripts by editing clip2r.js replacing Rgui in the js script with whatever is the appropriate word to locate python, julia, octave or other R front end assuming again that they are running.

Now to invoke it from within Bowpad:

1. ensure that your Rgui session is already running and
2. from within Bowpad select the code you want to run and copy it to the clipboard and then invoke Run R.  For example, to run everything use ctrl A ctrl C ctrl R 0 assuming that Run R is in position 0 in the configure menu.  Alternately use the mouse with the Ribbon.

Regarding the comment about difficulty finding help, it looks like Bowpad is based on [Scintilla](https://www.scintilla.org/) so the documentation for it and the related SciTE editor likely apply to Bowpad too.  You can also check the Bowpad source code on [github](https://github.com/stefankueng/BowPad).

Comment: Wow, it works! Fantastic !

Comment: One more thing, how can I modify your `clip2r.js` to merge your first two shortcut key combination `Ctrl+A (select all code, or optionally just select target code )` and `Ctrl+C`. I mean I want just two steps: (1) select all or part code; (2) press `Ctrl+R+0` to send and run the code simultaneously. I tried to change `wsh.SendKeys("% x%{w}1^{v}");` to `wsh.SendKeys("% ^{c}x%{w}1^{v}");`, where I guess `^{c}` means `Ctrl+C`, but it fails! @G. Grothendieck

Comment: That code is sending the ctrl C to Rgui.  Place focus on BowPad and then send ctrl C.

Comment: Also sending the ctrl C to BowPad won't necessarily work if you have multiple instances of BowPad.  If you leave it as in the answer then it will work with multiple instances.  If you want to go to the next level of sophistication write a jscript BowPad plugin.  https://tools.stefankueng.com/BowPad_plugins.html  https://github.com/stefankueng/BowPad/tree/main/plugins

Comment: Got it! Your solution is well enough to practical work!  @G. Grothendieck